# Why is Phusion Passenger refusing to recognize my updated RubyGems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger

I've updated RubyGems everywhere I can possibly think to update it:

[The various places I've updated RubyGems http://files.droplr.com/files/14167865/zel8k.Screen%20shot%202010-03-09%20at%2017:24:59.png](http://files.droplr.com/files/14167865/zel8k.Screen%20shot%202010-03-09%20at%2017:24:59.png)

but Phusion passenger keeps throwing the same error:

[Error Screenshot http://files.droplr.com/files/14167865/zee8W.Screen%20shot%202010-03-09%20at%2017:19:50.png](http://files.droplr.com/files/14167865/zee8W.Screen%20shot%202010-03-09%20at%2017:19:50.png)

There is that one freaking place that shows 1.3.1 as the version, despite the file name of 1.3.6. I've obviously borked things up pretty badly here.

That is, I need to update to 1.3.2 or greater and that I currently have 1.3.1.

Any idea how in the world I can get PP to use the correct version of RubyGems and preferably change things so I don't have to face this problem again?

Could this have anything to do with different paths for RubyGems and Ruby environments? These are my environments:

[Environment screenshots http://files.droplr.com/files/14167865/zfH6x.Screen%20shot%202010-03-09%20at%2019:07:18.png](http://files.droplr.com/files/14167865/zfH6x.Screen%20shot%202010-03-09%20at%2019:07:18.png)

Answer (score 0):

That might be of several reasons.

First, verify that you don't have it to explicitly require the rubygem in environment.rb. That is, if you have a line like this:

```
config.gem "ruby_gems", :version => "1.3.1"
```

Then you'll have to remove the version from it.

Also, seeing that the rubygems-update gives the incorrect version, you might want to uninstall it.

```
sudo gem uninstall rubygems-update
```

Since you have updated it, that gem is not necessary anymore.

I don't think it will help, but I would probably uninstall the macports version of rubygem as well since that might create collisions, even though it doesn't seem like it in this case.

**Update:**

Since you are using the Ruby from the operating system you don't have to install rubygem through macports at all.
To remove it:

```
sudo port uninstall rubygems
```

After that, make sure that you have upgraded the correct rubygem (the binary shows correct, but perhaps there is something missing)

```
sudo gem update --system
```

After you've done that. Open up `irb` (that is, irb and not the rails console) and check the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
puts Gem::RubyGemsVersion
```

Also, if you could paste how your *apache/nginx* configuration looks like, I doubt there is anything wrong in there, but you never know.

Comment: Thanks so much for chiming in, Jimmy. For starters, the environment.rb file is all right. No mention of it, and I have the exact same contents as the rest of my team, whom it's all working for, so it's likely a local issue. About to do some uninstalling and reporting back.

Comment: Do I install **all of MacPorts** or somehow just the rubygem?

Answer (score 0):

First, obtain the value of your PassengerRuby configuration. Then use that Ruby interpreter to run the following script:

http://pastie.org/862871

Like this:

```
/path-to-your-passenger-ruby-interpreter myscript.rb
```

and follow the instructions.